# Order by where conditions

Tags: mysql, regular-expression, regex

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE
key REGEXP 'some long regular expression'
OR key REGEXP 'some other long regular expression'

ORDER BY
key REGEXP 'some long regular expression' DESC,
key REGEXP 'some other long regular expression' DESC
```

Is there a cleaner way to get the same result as above, without repeating the `where` conditions in `order by`?

Comment: Use a subquery, alias the columns and order by the alias in the main (outer) query.

Comment: I think there's something wrong in your example that is slightly different from your actual situation: surely you need to compare the result of `regexp` with `1` or `0` in the `where` clause expressions? Or does MySQL treat `1` as `true` and `0` as `false`?

Comment: It appears to be working without the comparison, I guess it's not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    t.*,
    key REGEXP 'some long regular expression' AS a,
    key REGEXP 'some other long regular expression' AS b
  FROM table t
  WHERE a OR b
)
ORDER BY a DESC, b DESC;
```

Comment: Great! I moved the where clause outside the subquery because MySQL doesn't seem to recognize the alias in there, but this works!

Comment: Silly me, yes the `where` clause also needs to be outside the subquery. Basically the technique is to add the complicated expressions as new columns in the subquery -- or you can even use a `with` clause if your DBMS supports it.

Comment: Better yet, use HAVING a OR b _inside_ and no WHERE outside.  That will shrink the tmp table, thereby improving performance slightly.

Comment: @Colin'tHart Could you please indicate where the "key" syntax within a query is documented in MySQL? Rick - could you please write out the query you have in mind?

Comment: @Vérace What "key" syntax? In this example, `key` is just a column name -- which I copied from the question.

Comment: <Doh... slaps forehead in a Homer Simpsonesque gesture, and feeling dumber than Homer at the moment!). Of course - I thought it was some obscure MySQL hack/workaround that I had missed (i.e. a smart way of providing indexes/keys on the fly?). Another one down to the use of keywords as table/field names :-)